# No HTML4 or XHTML1 validation error

Tags: html

I am using the popular SEO software Brightedge at my company and it is telling me for over 2k+ pages that there is "No HTML4 or XHTML1 validation". Im not sure what this error means. Hoping someone can help me. I do use the doctype tag in the beginning of every HTML page. I am also using PHP to generate a header template for each page.

Answer (score 0):

This tool might be using w3c validation for your html pages. One of the page's html (complete) at http://validator.w3.org/ and see what you getting there.

Comment: i just tried it dont really see anything related to that

Comment: It sounds like Brightedge can not validate the HTML4/XHTML1 files. I am not aware of how the w3c validator could help you out in this situation anyway. How about contacting the maintainer? It's a commercial tool, so I claim you paid for it and are able to receive support?

Comment: yeah i can definitely receive support i will try that then, thanks

Comment: Just as a hint: it would be great if you could answer this question, when you received the necessary support. This will help anybody who may be in the same situation, stumbling across this post, some day ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is an important error! It is discovering pages that need to be updated to the latest version of HTML (Currently HTML5). An unlikely error if you are utilizing a common CMS like Wordpress, or Shopify, but could be an old custom site or another stack that has not been updated.